# Tomcat - asynchronous task for websocket servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, servlets, websocket

I have a small Java Websocket Servlet running on Tomcat 8.0.5.
Usually, it answers every received message immediately. But in some use case, it would be nice to have a scheduled event, that runs exactly once after some delay and sends new messages to clients.
I've already done some research, but I am not sure whether those articles fit my requirements:

[How to run a background task in a servlet based web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691132/how-to-run-a-background-task-in-a-servlet-application/4691650#4691650)

[How to schedule a task in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226126/how-to-schedule-a-task-in-tomcat)

My approach to solve this would be some kind of a Service, that takes an integer for the delay and some other required parameters. Based on that it creates a new Thread that will send some new messages after doing Thread.sleep(integer).

Is that an appropriate solution or is there some 'best practice' to solve this?

Comment: what about quartz scheduler?

Comment: What you should do is apply a limited thread pool; just spawning threads at will is not a good idea in a threaded server environment as you can seriously disrupt the server's ability to manage resources. The ExecutorService noted by Oleg can help to do this, but Quartz also internally uses a thread pool so it too is a decent solution with lots of flexibility.

Comment: @IwishIcouldthinkofagood quartz really looks like a nice way to do this - but isn't it some kind of overkill to use a scheduling framework for this? I do not know how much it impacts to performance - Would you use it in my use case?

Comment: @Gimby I just started to read Olegs answer - unfortunately I pressed F5 and it looks like he deleted it ...

Comment: Weird, it was a decent enough answer. The gist of the matter is: don't just spawn threads, apply a limited thread pool. Its up to you to decide what is overkill and what is not.